# PHP Pop3 Mail Parse

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a script to poll a pop3 mailbox and extract some contents of the email body which is in MIME. The below script does the job however it only reads the first message because the $message variable is manually defined to look at the first message only. I need this script to loop and get all the messages in the inbox. I don't do programming for living so please excuse my ignorance if this is a simple task.

Below code was extracted from http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/parse-emails-in-php-with-email-piping-part-2#.WnGfF2995EZ

```
require('mime_parser.php');
require('rfc822_addresses.php');
require('pop3.php');
stream_wrapper_register('mlpop3', 'pop3_stream');  /* Register the pop3 stream handler class */
$user=UrlEncode("someuserid");
$password=UrlEncode("somepassword");
$realm=UrlEncode("");                         /* Authentication realm or domain            */
$workstation=UrlEncode("");                   /* Workstation for NTLM authentication       */
$host = 'someip';
$apop=0;                                      /* Use APOP authentication                   */
$authentication_mechanism=UrlEncode("USER");  /* SASL authentication mechanism             */
$debug=0;                                     /* Output debug information                  */
$html_debug=1;                                /* Debug information is in HTML              */
$message=1;
$message_file='mlpop3://'.$user.':'.$password.'@'.$host.'/'.$message.
    '?debug='.$debug.'&html_debug='.$html_debug.'&realm='.$realm.'&workstation='.$workstation.
    '&apop='.$apop.'&authentication_mechanism='.$authentication_mechanism;


$mime=new mime_parser_class;

$mime->decode_bodies = 1;

$parameters=array(
    'File'=>$message_file,

    /* Read a message from a string instead of a file */
    /* 'Data'=>'My message data string',              */

    /* Save the message body parts to a directory     */
    /* 'SaveBody'=>'/tmp',                            */

    /* Do not retrieve or save message body parts     */

);
$success=$mime->Decode($parameters, $decoded);

if(!$success)
    echo '<h2>MIME message decoding error: '.HtmlSpecialChars($mime->error)."</h2>\n";
else
{


    if($mime->Analyze($decoded[0], $results))
    {
        //for($line=0;$line<count($decoded);$line++)

        $fromName = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['from:'][0]['name'];
        $fromEmail = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['from:'][0]['address'];

            //get the subject
            $subject = $decoded[0]['Headers']['subject:'];
            echo '<pre>';

            //get the message body
            if(substr($decoded[0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Body'])){

                $body = $decoded[0]['Body'];

            } elseif(substr($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Body'])) {

                $body = $decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Body'];

            } elseif(substr($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Body'])) {

                $body = $decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Body'];

            }

            echo "\nFrom: $fromName \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nAffected Sites: $searchmsg ";

            echo '</pre>';

    }
    else
        echo 'MIME message analyse error: '.$mime->error."\n";
}
```

Comment: I've figured out a way to do this and it works but not very elegant. Keen to know if others have a different method.